# How to merge css or How to use class in JS instead of id

Tags: javascript, html, css

In One of My application for input field I am geeting this design.

Pic [image: App1 Design]
My code

```
<input class="myCombo-combobox" name="language" style="width:30%;">
```

My CSS

```
.textbox {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #95B8E7;
  background-color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.textbox .textbox-text {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
  outline-style: none;
  resize: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.textbox .textbox-text::-ms-clear,
.textbox .textbox-text::-ms-reveal {
  display: none;
}
.textbox textarea.textbox-text {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.textbox .textbox-prompt {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #aaa;
}
.textbox .textbox-bgicon {
  background-position: 3px center;
  padding-left: 21px;
}

.textbox-addon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.textbox-label-after {
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.textbox-label-top {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0;
}
.textbox-disabled,
.textbox-label-disabled {
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}

.combo-arrow {
  width: 18px;
  height: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.6;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
}
.combo-arrow-hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
.combo-panel {
  overflow: auto;
}
.combo-arrow {
  background: url('images/combo_arrow.png') no-repeat center center;
}
.combo-panel {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.combo-arrow {
  background-color: #E0ECFF;
}
.combo-arrow-hover {
  background-color: #eaf2ff;
}
.combo-arrow:hover {
  background-color: #eaf2ff;
}
.combo .textbox-icon-disabled:hover {
  cursor: default;
}
.combobox-item,
.combobox-group,
.combobox-stick {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 3px;
}
.combobox-item-disabled {
  opacity: 0.5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.combobox-gitem {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.combobox-group,
.combobox-stick {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.combobox-stick {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  background: inherit;
}
.combobox-item-hover {
  background-color: #eaf2ff;
  color: #000000;
}
.combobox-item-selected {
  background-color: #ffe48d;
  color: #000000;
}
.combobox-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

The other places I am creating my input field like this way

Pic  [image: App 2 Design]

```
var myTable = '<input type="text" class="combobox"; style="width:30%;" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type in a name">' +
    '<table id="myTable">' + '<tr class="header"></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>' + '</table>';
```

My CSS

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#myInput {
  background-image: url('Drop.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#tdiv{
    height : 30%;
    overflow-y:auto;

}

tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: none;
  margin-top:-12px;
}

#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
  width : 10%;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  order-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#myInput:focus + #myTable{
  display: block;
}

#myTable:hover{
 display: block;
}
```

For My second application also I want the first kind of design. How to make with css because I am using id insted of class.
2. Is it possible that input data from table should be underlined and ";" seperated.

Comment: i dont' understand. why don't you use the same class on the second input as on the first ?

Comment: This is exactly what classes are for. To reuse.

Comment: My doubt is if I use class like `<input type="text" class = myCombo-combobox; style="width:30%;" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" ` this then what happened with id. Do I need to remove complete css of what I am using.

Comment: @Martijn Exactly But What about id. Can css load from id too ?

Comment: You are confusing yourself a lot. ID is to uniquely identify an element. Classes are used to give multiple elements similar styling. Having class has no effect on ID or vice-versa.

Comment: I suggest you read up on CSS, because you're missing a few basics.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: use classes for styling, use IDs when you need to use javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use the same class for the same styling. You can use class and id together. A class is used to put the same styles for many items and id is a unique identifier.

If you want a drop down, use

```
<select class="myCombo-combobox" name="language" style="width:30%;" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()">
    <option> A </option>
    <option> B </option>
    <option> C </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Table is displaying.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The problem was I wanted to use the second UI in my first Application and Now it is reflecting. Now Arrow is not coming while using second CSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146155/discussion-between-leah-and-david).

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes allow reuse, i.e. applying the same style to several elements.

You can use both id and class together in the HTML element, and CSS rules selecting by id and/or class too.

If different CSS rules apply to the same element, in case of conflict, the "closest" one takes precedence. For id vs class selectors, the id is more specific, thus the id CSS rule would have higher priority than the one related to the class. If there is no conflict, they are both applied.